# React lazy load modules with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a file called `routes.js`

```js
import Country from '../src/components/country/Country';
import Countries from '../src/components/country/CountriesList';

export const routes = [
{
    name: 'COUNTRY',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Create',
        path: '/country',
        component: Country,
      },
      {
        name: 'Update',
        path: '/update-country',
        component: Country,
        isHidden: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'View',
        path: '/countries',
        component: Countries,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

In my app.js I import routes and do something like this

```html
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Login}></Route>
  <Route path="/permission-denied" exact component={PermissionDenied}></Route>

  {routes
    .flatMap((items) => items.children)
    .map(({ component, path }) => (
      <ProtectedRoute component={component} exact path={path} />
    ))}

  <Route component={NotFound}></Route>
</Switch>;
```

This works without errors! But I want to split my code to reduce my bundle size.
How do I do it in `routes.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with react.lazy:

```js
import { lazy } from 'react';

// just change these lines
const Country = lazy(() => import('../src/components/country/Country'));
const Countries = lazy(() => import('../src/components/country/CountriesList'));

export const routes = [
{
    name: 'COUNTRY',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Create',
        path: '/country',
        component: Country,
      },
      {
        name: 'Update',
        path: '/update-country',
        component: Country,
        isHidden: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'View',
        path: '/countries',
        component: Countries,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

NOTE: Make sure you have a `Suspense` component with a `fallback` prop somewhere in your tree above where you are rendering these components.

Like this:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';


<Suspense fallback={<></>}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login}></Route>
        <Route path="/permission-denied" exact component={PermissionDenied}></Route>

        {routes
            .flatMap((items) => items.children)
            .map(({ component, path }) => (
            <ProtectedRoute component={component} exact path={path} />
            ))}

        <Route component={NotFound}></Route>
    </Switch>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: Is this same as this `const Country = () => import('../src/components/country/Country');` ?

Comment: @PathumKalhan - no, you need to pass a callback to `React.lazy` that loads the component only when it is rendered.